# Residue of a complex function at some pole.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

How can one visualize residue of a complex valued function at some given pole? I know how to find it. but I want to know its  significance and its geometric nature. Why do we study it? thank you.

Comment: It's the local obstruction to the existence of a primitive of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a complex function $f(z)$, we call $\bar{f(z)}$ the polya vector field of $f(z)$. If $f$ is analytic, the polya vector field is *divergenceless* and *irrotational*, meaning that it can be thought of as fluid flow or an electric field.

In this interpretation, a residue is just a point charge, with the magnitude of the residue measuring the magnitude of the charge. Similarly for fluid flow, a residue measures a *source* or *sink* at a given point.

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255464/what-mathematics-questions-can-be-better-solved-with-concepts-from-physics/532945#532945) of mine for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Much of the significance comes from the Residue Theorem, which says that (under the appropriate conditions)  the integral of $f$ around a closed contour depends only on the residues of $f$ at the singularities of $f$ inside that contour.
So, lots of integrals (including, as it turns out, many that have practical applications) can be easily computed using residues.